# Kibana5 behind reverse proxy iis

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, kibana-5

How can I put my kibana5 behind a iis reverse proxy?
My url is myserver/kibana5/ which is redirect to localhost:5601 but when I try to access to my kibana trought myserver/kibana5/, the url is transform to myserver/app/kibana/.
Without kibana5, this can't work.

Someone have the solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with the support :
-Modify basepath in kibana cfg file to /kibana5
-Modify IIS to accept invalid char like * and configure your reverse proxy

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to kibana.yml file is in kibana home --> config, and change the host to yours kibana server and delete the # char

Comment: Here my kibana cfg
https://pastebin.com/RJDHirmr

(I have tried with my ip and server name too for info)

Comment: double server? what does it mean? Can you explain more about the resolution?

Comment: I think you have error in the yml file, you have double "sever."